# How to save a variable in between application sessions [Access VBA]

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a variable that stores a file path. If the file is missing, the application prompts the user to select a new file. How can I save the new file path for the next time the user opens the program?

I know I could write the file path to a table and then retrieve it at runtime, but is there a way to do it strictly in VBA code?

Comment: SaveSetting / GetSetting is the simplest (Uses the registry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex K. said. This will save and retrieve values from the registry. For NameOfYourProject you might want to use the spreadsheet name or something.

```
SaveSetting "NameOfYourProject", "frmMain", "LastPath", szLastPath

szLastPath = GetSetting("NameOfYourProject", "frmMain", "LastPath", 0)
```

Here are the parameters for SaveSettings.

**AppName**
Required. String expression containing the name of the application or project to which the setting applies.

**Section**
Required. String expression containing the name of the section in which the key setting is being saved.

**Key**
Required. String expression containing the name of the key setting being saved.

**Setting**
Required. Expression containing the value to which Key is being set.

And these for GetSetting

**AppName**
Required. String expression containing the name of the application or project whose key setting is requested.

**Section**
Required. String expression containing the name of the section in which the key setting is found.

**Key**
Required. String expression containing the name of the key setting to return.

**Default**
Optional. Expression containing the value to return if no value is set in the Key setting. If omitted, Default is assumed to be a zero-length string ("").